# Circular insets in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-desktop, autocad, layouts

Looking for a way to add an AutoCad-type circular inset in ArcGIS 10.1. Have tried many different methods but the best we have been able to do is shown here

[image: here]

using "insert picture" after various image/raster processes.

Comment: @Dan, did you ever land any luck with exporting your map without the white fill around the inset showing up?

Answer (score 8):

You can do this in the Data Frame Properties for the inset window, under the Frame tab, use the Rounding setting. For a circle, just start with a square data frame and then set the rounding to 100%.

[image]

Comment: Good one! nice little cartographic trick

Comment: When I do this, and then export it to a PDF - it adds a square around the outside of the rounded dataframe.  Any work arounds for this issue?

Comment: @dklassen Try exporting to PNG instead, or TIF. I've seen the square pop up when exporting to PDF or JPG.

Comment: @DanC Both PNG and TIF work, but when I bump up the DPI to a reasonalble number (i.e. 250) it doesn't work again - square pops up again! Frustrating, they give you the ability to do it but only in the MXD.

Comment: The white square around a curved data frame is a known bug up to ArcMap 10.3. http://support.esri.com/technical-article/000002769 It occurs when a data frame with a raster image (or a vector data that has transparency set) is laid on top of another data frame. This bug was fixed in ArcGIS Pro. It can be avoided in ArcMap by not using a raster image, or removing any transparency applied to the overlaid data frame.